# zoomToCategory on amchart column chart

Tags: javascript, zooming, amcharts

I am developing a chart via amcharts and i want it to select certain ranges because i deal with more than 6000 x values on my map..i was trying to use zoomToCategory control on my map but when i use it the map doesn't appear.. :( ..any reason why??? the following is my code. :)

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>

        <head>

            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>amCharts examples</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/amcharts/images/style.css" type="text/css">
            <script src="http://localhost/amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
            <script type="text/javascript">

                var chart;

                var chartData = JSON.parse('<%=sjson%>');// [{ "Ip": "0", "Count": "10" }, { "Ip": "1", "Count": "11" }, { "Ip": "2", "Count": "12" }, { "Ip": "3", "Count": "13" }, { "Ip": "4", "Count": "14" }, { "Ip": "5", "Count": "15" }, { "Ip": "6", "Count": "16" }, { "Ip": "7", "Count": "17" }, { "Ip": "8", "Count": "18" }, { "Ip": "9", "Count": "19"}];



                AmCharts.ready(function () {
                    // SERIAL CHART
                    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
                    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
                    chart.categoryField = "Ip";
                    chart.startDuration = 1;

                    // AXES
                    // category
                    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
                    categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90;
                    categoryAxis.gridPosition = "Count";

                    // value
                    // in case you don't want to change default settings of value axis,
                    // you don't need to create it, as one value axis is created automatically.

                    // GRAPH
                    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                    graph.valueField = "Count";
                    graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: [[value]]";
                    graph.type = "column";
                    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
                    graph.fillAlphas = 0.8;

                    graph.zoomToCategoryValues("1", "10");
                    chart.addGraph(graph);

                    chart.write("chartdiv");
                });
            </script>

        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Please help me on this one...drilling down the x axes on this grpah is really important because of the huge number of data it shows.. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for anyone who will come accross this problem with column charts..it took me 2 days but for some it might be a pretty obvious answer, so here goes, this code adds amcchart scrollbar to a column chart in javascript. :)

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>

        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>amCharts examples</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
            <script src="../amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var chart;

                var chartData = [{"Ip":"0","Count":"10"},{"Ip":"1","Count":"11"},{"Ip":"2","Count":"12"},{"Ip":"3","Count":"13"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"}];



                AmCharts.ready(function () {
                    // SERIAL CHART
                    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
                    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
                    chart.categoryField = "Ip";
                    chart.startDuration = 1;
                    chart.pathToImages = "http://localhost/images/";
                    //scrollbar definition
                    var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();

                    // AXES
                    // category
                    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
                    //categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90;
                    categoryAxis.gridPosition = "Count";

                    // value
                    // in case you don't want to change default settings of value axis,
                    // you don't need to create it, as one value axis is created automatically.

                    // GRAPH
                    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                    graph.valueField = "Count";
                    graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: [[value]]";
                    graph.type = "column";
                    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
                    graph.fillAlphas = 0.8;

                    //add scrollbar to graph
                    chartScrollbar.graph = graph;
                    chartScrollbar.scrollbarHeight = 40;
                    chartScrollbar.color = "#FFFFFF";
                    chartScrollbar.autoGridCount = true;
                    chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

                    chart.addGraph(graph);

                    chart.write("chartdiv");
                });
            </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
        </body>

    </html>
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

graph doesn't have zoomToCategoryValues method, only chart has.
And you can't call this method before the chart is initialized.

You should listen for "init" or "dataUpdated" event and call a method which would do the zoom then:

```
// this line shoulf go to AmCharts.ready function:
chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);

// this is a method which will be called after the event is fired:
function zoomChart() {
     chart.zoomToCategoryValues("1", "10");
}
```

Comment: hey, thank you very much for the reply, much appreciated, :) but the scroll-bar feature allowed me to zoom into categories, rather select the categories i want to dynamically. :) :) so that what i was expecting. I will try out the code you mentioned also since it was my initial approach.. thanks again for your help :)